# XSLT Merge challenge

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

Firstly, I suck at XSLT. Secondly, I know there are several articles on how to perform merges with XSLT, but I didn't find anything on my particular challenge.

I have 2 XML files. One is new Customer Information and the other is the Current/Previous information below. I need the resultant XML to merge all of the Customer/Addresses and add attributes (NoChange, Updated, Deleted, New) to the attribute of the final XML:

---

#### Input 1

Current Customer Information.

```
<Customer>
 <CustId>1</CustId>
 <CustName>Acme</CustName>
 <Addresses>
  <Address>
   <AddressesId>1</AddressesId>
   <Street>123 Main</Street>
  </Address>
  <Address>
   <AddressesId>2</AddressesId>
   <Street>345 Main</Street</Street>
  </Address>
  <Address>
   <AddressesId>4</AddressesId>
   <Street>888 Goner St.</Street>
  </Address>
 </Addresses>
</Customer>
```

---

#### Input 2

Updates Information.

```
<Customer>
 <CustId>1</CustId>
 <CustName>Acme</CustName>
 <Addresses>
  <Address>
   <AddressesId>2</AddressesId>
   <Street>999 Updated St.</Street>
  </Address>
  <Address>
   <AddressesId>3</AddressesId>
   <Street>3999 New St.</Street>
  </Address>
 </Addresses>
</Customer>
```

---

#### Result

```
<Customer>
 <CustId>1</CustId>
 <CustName>Acme</CustName>
 <Addresses>
  <Address>
   <Address status="NoChange">
   <AddressesId>1</AddressesId>
   <Street>123 Main</Street>
  </Address>
  <Address>
   <Address status="Updated">
   <AddressesId>2</AddressesId>
   <Street>999 Updated St.</Street>
  </Address>
   <Address status="New">
   <AddressesId>3</AddressesId>
   <Street>3999 New St.</Street>
  </Address>
  <Address status="Deleted">
   <AddressesId>4</AddressesId>
   <Street>888 Goner St.</Street>
  </Address>
 </Addresses>
</Customer>
```

How can I do the merge I want?

Comment: There is a contradiction in the provided result. Why for Id = 1 the result is `<Address status="NoChange">` and for Id = 4 the result is `<Address status="Deleted">` ? . It seems to me that either both must be with status "deleted" or both must be with status "NoChange". Please explain in a comeent and also edit the question and correct.

Comment: I forgot to include the AddressId1 in the second file. I had re-edited my post. Thanks you, I will test this out.

Comment: Omg. It worked like a charm. I just registered for this site and as soon as I get enough, I will give you a vote. Please let me know how I can ever help you DN.

Comment: You are welcome. :) Just ask other interesting questions like this one :)

Comment: I'm at the office and this browser doesn't work well with stackOverflow.  I will post details on another related matter when I get home. Is there a way to 'genericze' the XSL?  I've been reading some articles written by you on how to apporach this. More to come...

Comment: I'm using a proprietary platform and we are not going use files nor are able to pass more than one input, so I will 'combine' the New and Origial Customer updates into one document and change the XSL to compare Customer[0] and Customer[1]. The part I'm curious about is how to make it generic enough to handle anything about the Customer (Address,Accounts, etc.) of which may have children themselves. I'm reading some of your articles to see if this question has been asked about traversing through andy document and applying the logic on any of the elements/nodes(?).

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 / XPath 2.0 there is the `deep-equal()` function. In XSLT such "general" comparison may be much more difficult and is a topic for a separate question. Even formulating this question is a challenging task.

Comment: I know. I'm doing reading and research now. I like to put in work until I really get stuck. I had tried for a week straight on this issue I had posted. I must have read over 30 articles and searching over 50 sites before asking for help.

Comment: Got it working. Used Oliver Becker's information as the starting point.

Comment: That's great. So, what *is* the problem?  :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307038/xslt-merge-challenge-pt-ii.  Question may not be %100 clear, sory in a bit of a rush. Will post more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I. This XSLT 1.0 transformation** (a corresponding XSLT 2.0 solution is shorter and easier):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kAddrById" match="Address"
  use="concat(../../CustId, '+', ../../CustName,
              '+', AddressesId)"/>

 <xsl:key name="kNodeByGenId" match="node()"
          use="generate-id()"/>

 <xsl:param name="pUpdatesPath" select=
  "'file:///c:/temp/delete/CustomersUpdates.xml'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vUpdates" select=
   "document($pUpdatesPath)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vmainDoc" select="/"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Addresses">
  <Addresses>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Address | $vUpdates/*/*/*">
    <xsl:sort select="AddressesId" data-type="number"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </Addresses>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Address">
   <xsl:variable name="vIsThisUpdate" select=
     "generate-id(/) = generate-id($vUpdates)"/>

   <xsl:variable name="vOtherDoc" select=
    "$vmainDoc[$vIsThisUpdate]
    |
     $vUpdates[not($vIsThisUpdate)]
    "/>

    <xsl:variable name="vCustId" select="../../CustId"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vCustName" select="../../CustName"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vAddrId" select="AddressesId"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vOtherNodeId">
     <xsl:for-each select="$vOtherDoc">
       <xsl:value-of select=
       "generate-id(key('kAddrById',
                        concat($vCustId,'+', $vCustName,
                               '+', $vAddrId)
                       )
                   )"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="selected"
     select="self::node()
              [$vIsThisUpdate
             or
              (not($vIsThisUpdate) and not(string($vOtherNodeId)))
              ]">
     <xsl:with-param name="pIsUpdating" select="$vIsThisUpdate"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="pOtherDoc" select="$vOtherDoc"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="pOtherNodeId"
                     select="string($vOtherNodeId)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Address" mode="selected">
  <xsl:param name="pIsUpdating"/>
  <xsl:param name="pOtherDoc" select="/.."/>
  <xsl:param name="pOtherNodeId"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vStatus">
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$pIsUpdating and not($pOtherNodeId)">New</xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="$pIsUpdating">
         <xsl:variable name="vOldStreet">
          <xsl:for-each select="$pOtherDoc">
            <xsl:value-of select=
              "key('kNodeByGenId', $pOtherNodeId)/Street"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:variable>

         <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test=
           "Street = string($vOldStreet)">NoChange</xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>Updated</xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>Deleted</xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <Address>
    <Address status="{$vStatus}"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Address>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Customer>
    <CustId>1</CustId>
    <CustName>Acme</CustName>
    <Addresses>
        <Address>
            <AddressesId>1</AddressesId>
            <Street>123 Main</Street>
        </Address>
        <Address>
            <AddressesId>2</AddressesId>
            <Street>345 Main</Street>
        </Address>
        <Address>
            <AddressesId>4</AddressesId>
            <Street>888 Goner St.</Street>
        </Address>
    </Addresses>
</Customer>
```

**and having at `c:/temp/delete/CustomersUpdates.xml` this XML document** (slightly changed from the provided in order to have the first address end up with status "NoChange"):

```
<Customer>
    <CustId>1</CustId>
    <CustName>Acme</CustName>
    <Addresses>
        <Address>
            <AddressesId>1</AddressesId>
            <Street>123 Main</Street>
        </Address>
        <Address>
            <AddressesId>2</AddressesId>
            <Street>999 Updated St.</Street>
        </Address>
        <Address>
            <AddressesId>3</AddressesId>
            <Street>3999 New St.</Street>
        </Address>
    </Addresses>
</Customer>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Customer>
   <CustId>1</CustId>
   <CustName>Acme</CustName>
   <Addresses>
      <Address>
         <Address status="NoChange"/>
         <AddressesId>1</AddressesId>
         <Street>123 Main</Street>
      </Address>
      <Address>
         <Address status="Updated"/>
         <AddressesId>2</AddressesId>
         <Street>999 Updated St.</Street>
      </Address>
      <Address>
         <Address status="New"/>
         <AddressesId>3</AddressesId>
         <Street>3999 New St.</Street>
      </Address>
      <Address>
         <Address status="Deleted"/>
         <AddressesId>4</AddressesId>
         <Street>888 Goner St.</Street>
      </Address>
   </Addresses>
</Customer>
```

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kAddrById" match="Address"
  use="concat(../../CustId, '+', ../../CustName,
              '+', AddressesId)"/>

 <xsl:param name="pUpdatesPath" select=
  "'file:///c:/temp/delete/CustomersUpdates.xml'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vUpdates" select=
   "document($pUpdatesPath)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vmainDoc" select="/"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Addresses">
  <Addresses>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Address | $vUpdates/*/*/*">
    <xsl:sort select="AddressesId" data-type="number"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </Addresses>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Address[root() is $vUpdates]">
    <xsl:variable name="vOtherDoc" select="$vmainDoc"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vOtherNode" select="my:OtherNode(., $vOtherDoc)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vStatus" select=
     "concat('New'[not($vOtherNode)],
             'NoChange'[$vOtherNode 
                       and current()/Street eq $vOtherNode/Street],
             'Updated'[$vOtherNode and current()/Street ne $vOtherNode/Street]
             )"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="self::node()" mode="selected">
     <xsl:with-param name="pStatus" select="$vStatus"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Address[not(root() is $vUpdates)]">
   <xsl:variable name="vOtherDoc" select="$vUpdates"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vOtherNode" select="my:OtherNode(., $vOtherDoc)"/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="self::node()[not($vOtherNode)]" mode="selected">
      <xsl:with-param name="pStatus" select="'Deleted'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Address" mode="selected">
  <xsl:param name="pStatus"/>

  <Address>
    <Address status="{$pStatus}"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Address>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:OtherNode" as="element()?">
   <xsl:param name="pThis" as="element()"/>
   <xsl:param name="pOtherDoc" as="document-node()"/>

    <xsl:sequence select=
     "key('kAddrById',
          concat($pThis/../../CustId,'+', $pThis/../../CustName,
                 '+', $pThis/AddressesId
                 ),
                 $pOtherDoc
          )"/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same documents, the same correct result is produced.**

Answer (score 1):

I decided to try this as a use case for the new xsl:merge instruction in XSLT 3.0. Using the current Saxon implementation, the following gives the desired result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="original" select="doc('merge018-current.xml')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="updates" select="doc('merge018-updates.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template name="main">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$original"/>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="Addresses">
    <Addresses>
      <xsl:merge>
        <xsl:merge-source for-each="$updates, $original"
                        select=".//Address">
          <xsl:merge-key select="AddressesId"/>
        </xsl:merge-source>
        <xsl:merge-action>
          <xsl:variable name="status" select="
            if (count(current-group()) = 1)
            then if (current-group()[1]/root(.) is $original) then 'Deleted' else 'New'
            else if (deep-equal(current-group()[1], current-group()[2])) then 'NoChange' else 'Updated'"/>
          <Address status="{$status}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]/(AddressesId, Street)"/>
          </Address>
        </xsl:merge-action>
      </xsl:merge>
    </Addresses>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm not suggesting this as a practical solution, just providing it for your interest. If you have any objection to this or something similar being published as a test case, please say so now.

Comment: Any input to this discussion is welcomed.  Also, I have your book as a reference.